# Puppet templates without modules

Tags: puppet

I want to use puppet without a puppetmaster and apply manifests with a git push workflow. I'd like to avoid splitting up everything into modules, because the server config is not very complex. However, the `template()` function seems to have issues accessing templates that are not in modules.

If the manifest is located in `<puppet-root>/manifests/site.pp` how do I reference e.g. `<puppet-root>/templates/sshd_config.erb`?

Answer (score 0):

having a templates dir in puppet root should work, try the following:

```
file { '/tmp/testfile':
    content => template('puppet:///templates/testfile.erb'),
}
```

Comment: Isn't `puppet:///` only used in conjunction with a master? Also I have no client running. It's a simple puppet apply. No puppet server or client.

Comment: This seems like it should work, but I'm trying it now and it doesn't. #weaksauce